# Serve Multiple Clients from one PBIX File

Tags: powerbi

We are looking at a scenario in which we have an embedded Power BI report in a react application.  This Power BI report is app owned.

The goal is that when a client logs in to our React application, behind the scenes we use an embed token to log that user into Power BI and show the client just their data.

I know how to use Row Level Security to filter a single table so that users only see their own data.  The problem is that I found out that we're storing each client's data in their own table.  So, our table list might look like this:

data_c1
forecast_c1
data_c2
forecast_c2
data_c30121
forecast_c30121

The good news is that data and forecast have the same structure, just different client data.

What I don't want to do is create one PBIX file with all tables.  I also don't want to create one PBIX per client.  Is there a way to dynamically specify which tables to use at run time?  So, if I log into the report as Chris, I see client c1.  If I log in as Bob, I see client c30121.

If this were SQL in C#, I'd just do string query = "select * from data_" + clientName;

That doesn't seem possible in PowerBI.

Comment: Do you import the data or are you using directQuery?

Comment: Hi Wouter, we are using directQuery

Comment: You can create a view in the database, `union all`-ing all these tables, and adding one more column with client's ID or name, etc. Then in the report you can use RLS or filters to show only the relevant data.

Comment: We thought about that, but that could mean millions of rows unioned together.  That's why we partitioned the data into separate tables to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Hand off the work in the database to a stored proc.

You will have the username or whatever you generate as a token in embedded. Often we pipe through additional parameters like me@example.com|company=c30121 as the username in the token and then parse it in the RLS.

You could pass such a username composite off to a stored proc that uses [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which can then do all the heavy lifting, of both parsing your username and data processing.

Calling a Stored Proc can be "fun" from PowerBI, I have not done it for a few years. [Here is a good conversation](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Use-SQL-Store-Procedure-in-Power-BI/td-p/20269). Things may have improved since 2016...